# Why doesn't the checked pseudo class work in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, popup

I am trying to make a popup with html and css. Among the popup I want to customize my radio button, I am watching a video to guide me and I followed it like this in the video. The problem comes when I want to do the part that involves the pseudo class: checked in css because it does not work for me, that is, it does not let me click and select what I want

I would appreciate if anyone knows why it is

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
      <div class="popup">
        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><img src="C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\crowdfunding-product-page-main\images\icon-close-modal.svg" ></a>
        <h1>Back this project</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Want to support us in bringing Mastercraft Bamboo Monitor Riser out in the world?</p>
        <div class="modal-card">
          <input type="radio" value="Pledge with no reward">
          <label>Pledge with no reward</label>
            <br><br>
            <p>Choose to support us without a reward if you simply believe in our project. As a backer, 
    you will be signed up to receive product updates via email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vw;
}

.popup {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 44%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -32.5%; 
}

.modal-card {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.modal-card p {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;  
}

label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0 ,0 ,0.1);
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}

label:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 116 ,217 ,0.1);
} 

label::before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 2px;
}
 
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: #0074D9;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
}
```

This is the code that I have, before I had tried it with an internet code and it did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Because display of input is none, it cannot be checked.
I think you can add 'for' to label.

```
<input type="radio" value="Pledge with no reward" id="yourId">
<label for="yourId">Pledge with no reward</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the given code: Because the input is given display: none it isn't clickable; by using a radio button we haven't given the user any way of cancelling this choice should they decide they don't want to make an unrewarded pledge.

For the first problem we can position the input absolutely (so it doesn't affect the positioning of anything else) but with visibility: hidden - it therefore has 'space' on the page and can be clicked. If we link it to its label (using a 'for' attribute in the label and giving the input element an id) then clicking on the label will be spotted by the system and we can use that to alter the look of our circle.

For the second problem, in this snippet a checkbox rather than a radio button is used so the user can change their mind. It can of course be put back to a radio if that is what is really required.

```html
<head>
<style>
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vw;
}

.popup {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 44%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -32.5%; 
}

.modal-card {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.modal-card p {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

input#noreward {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;    
}

label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(0, 0 ,0 ,0.1);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

label:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 116 ,217 ,0.1);
} 

label::before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #0074D9 0%, #0074D9 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay">
      <div class="popup">
        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><img src="C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\crowdfunding-product-page-main\images\icon-close-modal.svg" ></a>
        <h1>Back this project</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Want to support us in bringing Mastercraft Bamboo Monitor Riser out in the world?</p>
        <div class="modal-card">
            <input id="noreward" type="checkbox" value="Pledge with no reward">
            <label for="noreward">Pledge with no reward</label>
            <br><br>
            <p>Choose to support us without a reward if you simply believe in our project. As a backer, 
    you will be signed up to receive product updates via email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```